# Onsen-UI - ons-tabbar page transition

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using ons-tabbar for app navigation, is there any "out of the box" page transition I could specify, i.e "slide in from right", when navigating tabs, or any "best practice?

```
<ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          active="true"
          label="Home"
          icon="home"
          page="navigator1.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          label="Create Item"
          icon="plus"
          page="navigator2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          label="View Items"
          icon="fa-lightbulb-o"
          page="browse.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          label="Settings"
          icon="gear"
          page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
</ons-tabbar>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it like this:

```
.topcoat-page__bg {
    -webkit-animation: pageleftright .25s;
    animation: pageleftright .25s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pageleftright {
    from {left: 100%;}
    to {left: 0;}
}

@keyframes pageleftright {
    from {left: 100%;}
    to {left: 0;}
}
```

Will work for pages with a  root element.

For regular pages: `<ons-page>`

```
.page {
    -webkit-animation: pageleftright .25s;
    animation: pageleftright .25s;
}
```

Mix them

```
.page, .topcoat-page__bg {
    -webkit-animation: pageleftright .25s;
    animation: pageleftright .25s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add animation attribute on Tabbar as below

```
<ons-tabbar animation="fade">
    <ons-tabbar-item
          active="true"
          label="Home"
          icon="home"
          page="navigator1.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          label="Create Item"
          icon="plus"
          page="navigator2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          label="View Items"
          icon="fa-lightbulb-o"
          page="browse.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
          label="Settings"
          icon="gear"
          page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
</ons-tabbar>
```

based on documentation valid values are only "none" and "fade"

http://onsen.io/guide/components.html#ons-tabbar

Answer (score 0):

I know this questions is super old, buuuut anyways :)

With OnsenUI v2 there's an `animation-options` attribute that accepts an object that should look somewhat familiar if you know any CSS:

`<ons-tabbar position="top | bottom | auto" animation="fade | slide | none" animation-options="{duration: 0.6, delay: 0, timing: 'ease-out'}">`

Current docs for JS: https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-tabbar.html#attributes